# Formatear número con decimales en javascript y llamarlo desde un div en html

Tags: javascript

estoy utilizando un javascript para dar formato de separación de miles y decimales a un número, me funciona con el console.log desde el javascript pero no logro que funcione desde el div del html que es el lugar donde va a estar el número que necesito formatear. 
Me pueden indicar que está mal? o cómo puedo hacerlo para que el número 123456789 que está en el html salga con formato de separación de miles.

Gracias

```js
function separators(num)
  {
    var num_parts = num.toString().split(".");
    num_parts[0] = num_parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return num_parts.join(".");
  }
  

console.log(separators(1000));
console.log(separators(10000.23));
console.log(separators(100000));
```

```html
<html>
<title>Formatear Numero</title>
<head>

</head>
 
<body>
 
<form>
<div type="number" class="formatNumber.new" id="numeritos">"1234567890"</div>
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ningún lado llamas la función que te formatea el número, puedes hacer una nueva funcion para llamar escribir el valor en tu div de la siguiente manera:

```
showNumber();

function separators(num)
{
    var num_parts = num.toString().split(".");
    num_parts[0] = num_parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return num_parts.join(".");
}

function showNumber() {
    document.getElementById("numeritos").innerHTML = separators(1234567890);
}
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que deberías obtener el texto en `numeritos` y reemplazar dicho texto por el formateado

Comment: En eso tienes razón @Marcos